# TEMP table in stored procedure oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any way to create a temp table with the stored procedure and use the same in the ref cursor in the same stored procedure.
I wrote something like below, it's not working....

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USP_TEST(
    CUR_QUOTE OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
    BEGIN
    CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE users1 ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
    AS
      SELECT 'rb@bot.com' FROM DUAL;
      OPEN CUR_QUOTE FOR
      SELECT DISTINCT CREATEDBY
      FROM QUOTE
      WHERE TRUNC(DATEOFENQUIRY)=TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) AND CREATEDBY = users1.EMAIL;
    END;
```

And delete the temp table at the end.
Please suggest with some sample code...
Keep coding :)

Comment: You are not using the global temporary table in your procedure(except creating it) so you can do whatever you want with that table. If you have used temp table in the cursor and if you delete the temp table at the end, then while opening the cursor from the caller block, you will receive an error. as the query of the cursor will be executed at that time.

Comment: you cannot not execute ddl directly in a procedure. Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to do this.

Comment: Additionally, I'd suggest you **not** to create objects dynamically unless you must. Here, I'd say you don't have to do that. Create it outside of the procedure, use it within.

Comment: More often than not, temp tables are the wrong approach to begin with

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the table then the cursor is invalidated.

From 18c you can use [private temporary tables](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c):

```
create or replace procedure usp_test
    ( cur_quote out sys_refcursor )
as
begin
    execute immediate
        'create private temporary table ora$ptt_demo' ||chr(10)||
        'on commit drop definition as' ||chr(10)||
        'select sysdate -1 as dateofenquiry, ''rb@bot.com'' as createdby' ||chr(10)||
        'from   dual';

    open cur_quote for
        'select distinct createdby from ora$ptt_demo where trunc(dateofenquiry) = trunc(sysdate - 1)';
end;
```

Note that the table name must have the prefix defined by the `PRIVATE_TEMP_TABLE_PREFIX` parameter (default `ORA$PTT_`), and you must commit before calling the procedure a second time.